# sed find and replace fails when string has a space in it

Tags: sed

I have a sample.txt file with contents as:

```
test sometest
test2 againsometext
```

My shell script uses sed to find the line which has "test" and replaces the whole line with "test google.com::100-ws sample.com::SAMPLE". sed fails with "unterminated `s' command".

```
#!/bin/sh

TEST1=test
TEST2=google.com::100-ws sample.com::GOLD-WS
echo $TEST1
echo $TEST2

if [[ ! -e sample.txt ]]; then
  touch sample.txt
  echo $TEST1 $TEST2 >> sample.txt
else
  grep -q $TEST1 sample.txt
  if [ $? -eq 0 ];then
     sed -i 's/^$TEST1 .*$/$TEST1 '$TEST2'/' sample.txt
  else
     echo $TEST1 $TEST2 >> sample.txt
  fi
fi
```

I have this same script in other places where the replacement text does not have any spaces and it works fine.

Can someone suggest some ideas to try?

TIA

Comment: `sh` ([Bourne-shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bourne_shell)) is usally not `bash` ([Bourne-again shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell))).

Comment: Please paste your script first at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: Why do you have those single quotes around `$TEST2`? What do you want the output to look like?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)  Briefly, `if grep -q "$TEST1" sample.txt; then sed -i "s/^$TEST1 .*\$/$TEST1 $TEST2/" sample.txt` (note also [Why is testing “$?” to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `bash` is available in your environment, it will be just
enough to say:

```
#!/bin/bash

test1="test"
test2="google.com::100-ws sample.com::GOLD-W"

sed -i "s/^$test1.*/$test1 $test2/" sample.txt
```

- You need to quote strings which contain blank character(s) to prevent word-splitting.
- It is not a good practice to use uppercase alphabets for normal variable names.
- You need to use not single quotes but double quotes to enable variable expansion as
  a command to `sed`.

Comment: This works. Thank you! I used upper case cos they are actually env variables. I changed name cos I cant share the real name.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I've understood why you picked uppercase variable names.

Answer (score 1):

That space between test and msg is important.  Otherwise you'll obliterate every line that begins with test.  Also you can backrefence `\1` your captured group `\(test \)`  https://regular-expressions.mobi/refcapture.html

```sh
#! /bin/bash
replace="google.com::100-ws sample.com::GOLD-W"
sed -i "s/^\(test \).*/\1$replace/" sample.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Appreciate it!